# Reading only selected data from file

Tags: c, file, input

I have a file with data written as in an example:

```
    text1 1542 542 6325 6523 3513 323
    text2 1232 354 5412 2225 2653 312
    text3 ....
    ...
```

I want my program to read and print only selected data, i.e. only 3rd and 4th column, every second row. So I need to skip the string "text1" at the beginning, but also the rest of the columns in the line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf with * modifier skips that part of data, so in your case do

```
fscanf(FilePointer,"%s %*d %*d %d %d", &col3, &col4);
```

it will read columns 3 and 4 as you wanted to.

Then you print them with regular

```
printf("%d %d\n", col3, col4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtok() to split the string specifying your delimiters (in this case a space).

Answer (score 0):

Hints to the most straightforward answer that I can think:

1. The easiest way to skip a line is to call `fgets` and ignore the
   obtained string.
2. To read seven strings (not containing blanks) from one line, use:

   ```
   scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7);
   ```

   If you want to treat some as numbers, replace `%s` with `%d` and, e.g., `s3` with `&n3`.
3. To print anything, just use `printf`...

Answer (score 0):

Here goes:

```
char buffer [512];
int lineNum = 0;  // or 1, if you need the odd rather than even numbered lines
int col3, col4;

while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), inputFile) {
    if (lineNum % 2) {
         sscanf (buffer, "%*s %*d %d %d", &col3, &col4)
         printf ("%d %d\n", col3, col4);
    }  // end if
    lineNum++;
} // end while
```

Haven't tried it, so debugging might be needed, but something like this should work.  Also, this just prints the numbers, but in real life you'll need to do whatever processing is needed to prevent those numbers being overwritten by the next read.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a function to skip rows as needed and a mask to identify which columns to print.

```
int FilterFile(FILE *inf, unsigned Row, unsigned ColumnMask) {
  char buffer[1024];
  unsigned RowCount = 0;
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inf) != NULL ) {
    if ((++RowCount) % Row)
      continue;
    const char *s = buffer;
    unsigned column = ColumnMask;
    while (*s && column)  {
      int start, end;
      sscanf(s, " %n%*s%n", &start, &end);
      if (1 & column) {
        printf("%.*s%c", end - start, &s[start], (column == 1) ? '\n' : ' ');
      }
      column >>= 1;
      s = &s[end];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}



int main() {
  const char *path = "../src/text.txt";
  FILE *inf = fopen(path, "rt");
  if (inf) {
    unsigned ColumnMask = 0;
    ColumnMask |= 1 << (2-1); // Print column 2
    ColumnMask |= 1 << (3-1); // Print column 3
    unsigned RowSkip = 2; // Print every 2nd row
    FilterFile(inf, RowSkip, ColumnMask);
    fclose(inf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```